# Error when creating new environment with python 3.4 in Anaconda

Tags: installation, anaconda, python-3.4, newenvironment

I'm trying to set up a Anaconda environment with Python=3.4 but I have been having a hard time to do it.

I have tried it with and without default packages

```
(base) C:\Users\Fabio Diuana>conda create --name py34_b python=3.4 --no-default-packages
(base) C:\Users\Fabio Diuana>conda create --name py34_b python=3.4
```

Both return the same error

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==10.1=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 10.1
```

Has anyone already faced this issue before? Any solutions?

`conda info`

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : D:\ProgFile\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\Fabio Diuana\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Fabio Diuana\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.1
       base environment : D:\ProgFile\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : D:\ProgFile\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Fabio Diuana\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Fabio Diuana\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : D:\ProgFile\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Fabio Diuana\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Fabio Diuana\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I have also posted it on Anaconda Github https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10079

Comment: not to ask a stupid question, but I suppose you have Python 3.4 installed on your machine?  How was it installed?

Comment: Hey I have installed it via Anaconda